# Element ID changing with each MYSQL Database insert

Tags: php

Ok so I have a script that pulls information from a database and puts it into a table. (the full script is at the bottom of this question)

Each TR is echoed with a standard ID: `echo "<tr class='task' id='task1'>";` the only problem with this is each new `tr` or each row that is pulled from the database gets assigned the same ID `task1` This is not good coding technique as well as not working with my javascript for changing the tables class name's based on the information from the database.

So my question is, is there a way to sort of "auto generate" the id name for each tr of the table? I would like to see task1, task2, task3 and so on.

**Full code starts here**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

    $query = "SELECT * FROM affiliate_tasks WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'";

                if( isset($_POST['sort-selection']) && $_POST['sort-selection'] != 'all' ) 
                {
                    $query .= " AND status = '". $_POST['sort-selection']."';" ;
                }

                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                echo "<table class='table table-message'>
                <tr class='heading'>
                <td class='cell-title'>Tasks</td> 
                <td class='cell-status hidden-phone hidden-tablet'>Status</td> 
                <td class='cell-time align-right'>Due Date</td>
                </tr>";

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                  {
                  echo "<tr class='task' id='task1'>";
                  echo "<td class='cell-ttle'>" . $row['task_name'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td class='cell-status hidden-phone hidden-tablet'>"  . $row['status'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td class='cell-time align=right'>" . $row['due_date'] . "</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                  }
                echo "</table>";

                mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your table row has an unique id column, that will be the best fit here. You can use:

```
echo "<tr class='task' id='task-" . $row['id'] . "'>";
```

If not, and you just want a sequential number, you just use a variable like this:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr class='task' id='task-" . ++$i . "'>";
  // Rest of your lines ...
}
```